# sqlcmd not showing RESTORE database stats

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-administration, sqlcmd, database-restore

The following command in a cmd window

```
sqlcmd -S. -Usa -Ppass -dmaster -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [MYDATABASE] FROM DISK = 'D:\SQL Server\MYDATABASE.BAK' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10"
```

displays the following progress output:

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 32320 pages for database 'MYDATABASE', file 'MYDATABASE' on file 1.
Processed 7 pages for database 'MYDATABASE', file 'MYDATABASE_log' on file 1.
```

But it turns that the progress is shown only **after** the entire restore, turning the stats during the process useless.

Any advice?

Here is the version of sqlcmd tool:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 12.0.2000.8 NT
Copyright (c) 2014 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
```

**Update Dec-2016:**

Just including the comment from [Microsoft Connect link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765019/raiserror-with-nowait-not-honoured-in-sqlcmd11) shared in comments:

> SQLCMD was rewritten in SQL 2012 to use ODBC. Here is a small
> regression error that appears to have sneaked in.

It's the same effect reported when calling `RAISERROR('Hello', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` along a script.

Comment: Having this same problem. I'll post if I find something.

Comment: Probably because of this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765019/raiserror-with-nowait-not-honoured-in-sqlcmd11

Comment: Probably because of your isolation level.

Comment: @Deadsheep39 I'm almost sure that the same command worked fine on previous versions. Could you please elaborate your comment? What does isolation level have to do with such behavior?

Comment: Whole restore is under implicit transaction. If you would like print result in the middle of transaction you have to use lower isolation level.

Comment: @Deadsheep39 I don't think restore database command messages are related to transaction isolation levels. Could you give some working example or any documentation around the topic?

Comment: You can also check the SQL Logs - the current log should show the messages in order as they're produced, so at least you can keep track of it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can query percent_complete in sys.dm_exec_requests.

Open a separate SQL window and issue the following command

```
select percent_complete from sys.dm_exec_requests where percent_complete > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can look in the SQL logs to see the progress ongoing.